# set up multiple worker nodes in a WSO2 DSS cluster fronting with ELB

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, wso2-data-services-server

I followed [this documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS301/Clustered+Deployment) to set up a minimum Data Services cluster; this includes a manager node, a worker node and fronting them I have ELB(Elastic Load Balancer).

It works perfectly, but I need to add another worker. Is there any documentation about how to set multiple worker nodes in this scheme?

I tried to add it following the same documentation, but the second worker node is not receiving any request from the manager: for example, if I shutdown "worker1", then the second worker is also not able to take the request.

The ELB log shows that there are no application members available, even when the second worker has supposedly correctly joined the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same configuration as the first worker node.  If you are running the workers on the same machine, you have to change `localMemberPort` in axis2.xml and Port Offset (`Offset`) in carbon.xml to different values to make sure that there are no conflicts. Also note that workers must be started as `sh wso2server.sh -DworkerNode=true`